# How do you match the individual words as separate words in the input sentence in a string that has just one word

Tags: java

I want to see if multiple words found inside the string. With O(n^2) complexity. For example: sunshine - sun, shine, hine. And will print collection of strings: sun shine and hine if it matches.  How do I check if a string contains a matching words?

```
//String search = sunshine 
public static boolean wordsInsideTheString(String search) { 
    String[] word = {"sun", "shine", "hine"};
    int counter = 0;    
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {      
       String[] words = word[i].split("\\s+");
       for (String check : words) 
           if(check.equalsIgnoreCase(search)) {
               counter++;
               break;
           } 
       }    
    return false;
}
```

Calling the method with:

```
assert.True(wordsInsideTheString("sunshine");
```

Comment: What do you actually want to print here?

Comment: true prints outs: sun, shine and hine

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to assert whether or not an input string matches a collection of words, then use `String#matches`:

```
public static boolean wordsInsideTheString(String search) { 
    String[] word = {"sun", "shine", "hine"};
    List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(word);
    String regex = ".*(?:" + String.join("|", wordList) + ").*";

    return search.matches(regex);
}
```

If instead you also want to print which of the terms did match, then we need to do a bit more work.  I suggest just iterating the array of word terms and again using `String#matches`:

```
public static boolean wordsInsideTheString(String search) { 
    String[] words = {"sun", "shine", "hine"};
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean match = false;
    for (String word : words) {
        if (search.contains(word)) {
            match = true;
            matches.add(word);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Matching words: " + String.join(",", matches));

    return match;
}
```

Comment: What about if complexity is O(n^2) two for loops

Comment: The second version only has _one_ loop.  Why would you think it is `O(n^2)`?

Comment: Since we have multiple values or it does no matter? What if we have 5 words not 3 words match the string.

Comment: There is really no avoiding at least a single loop, because each potential match has to be checked against the input string.

Comment: Your comment does not help me to update/iterate my answer.  Please be specific about what is not working.  I tested the code in a Java demo and it seems to work fine.

Comment: when I ran it says false and does not provide me strings output says: Matches and false;

Comment: What input are you passing to the method?

Comment: wordsInsideTheString(sunshine)

Comment: @Alex Try the updated answer.  I thought you wanted to match the individual words as _separate_ words somewhere in the input sentence.  If you want to match those _substrings_, it is different logic, but I have given it to you.

Comment: Isn't this `O(mn)` where m is the size if the words collection, and n is the length of the string to be searched? I assume the words collection isn't fixed at these specific 3 words.